# iOS - warning on a webview: Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have this code. the reference to theWebView is a WebView element that I put on the page.

I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.859 alpha:1.000];
    theWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

And I get a warning on this line:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.859 alpha:1.000];
```

saying:

```
Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'BalanceSheetController *const_strong'
```

Would anyone know why this warning happens? without that line, clicks on links on the UIWebView do not get recognized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your View controller most likely does not implement the *UIWebViewDelegate* protocol. Even if it has the methods, you probably don't have it in your interface declaration. It should look like:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Comment: yes, my .h file currently is declared like this: @ interface BalanceSheetController : UIViewController ...would you know what implication that has if any? And what implications would there be if I changed it to how you have it shown? thank you!

Comment: I suggest you read on Protocols and Delegates - because there's so much use of delegation pattern in Cocoa, you'll really find it useful. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html